# How to find eigenvalues for two matrices

Tags: python-3.x

here are my two vectors-:

```
y1=[2,3,4,5,6,7]
y2=[1,5,3,6,7,8]
```

when i solve it with pen and paper! 
it gives me an ans -: `y1= 1.117y2`

when i do that in python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
A = np.array([y1,y2])
w, v = LA.eig(A)
print(w)

print(v)
```

this error occurs `LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square`
how can i solve this problem!

please help me , how can i do that!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that eigenvalues can only exist for square matrices, therefore Numpy expects to see an n x n dimensional matrix and not an n x m dimensional matrix such as the 2 x 6 matrix A in your example.